# text mining and advanced search solution for sharepoint

Tags: java, sharepoint, enterprise-library, business-intelligence, text-mining

Within my organization, we have maintained a sharepoint site to store a large amount of files related to previous/ongoing projects. These files can be word, pdf and ppt files. We are interesting to build a solution that have following functionalities
1) Advanced search, return a set of files that matches the keyword input by users. It is better to mark the returned files with some label (like using color) on the contents that are directly related to the search keyword.
2) Enable users to perform some types of analysis on the sharepoint site. Such as social network analysis of the person who are authors of some sharepoint files.

Are there any commercial software or open source library to fulfill these types of tasks?

Comment: use opennlp it is probably a good starting point https://opennlp.apache.org/

Answer (score 1):

This response is assuming you are using SharePoint 2010 or 2013.

Consider using faceted search. If you have an Enterprise cal you can easily set this up.  The trick is making sure the metadata for the facets is available.  This would obtain the search behavior your looking for, but not the interaction and tagging.

For this it would be best to create a custom solution, and leverage term sets in managed metadata.  In SharePoint 2010 there is conditional formatting that you could use for color coding, however this is deprecated in 2013.

Hope those directions are helpful, but ultimately you are likely going to need to do a combination with custom code and event handlers.